# Cakephp session flash auth message via AJAX and jQuery validationEngine

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm trying to link login failure Session Flash Auth message with jQuery validation engine.

I have below in my login layout:

```
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

Is there a way so that if email exists the error message is shown like what validationEngine does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple use the right css. Just right click on the validationEngine error message and cpau and paste the css for .sucess/.error class